# How can I change the default FireFox "Unable to Connect" page?

Tags: firefox

I am using my `hosts` file to block ad-serving domains like doubleclick.net.

FireFox fills the blocked ad containers, be they frames or divs or whatever, with a page that says:

> **Unable to connect**
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at .
>     
> *   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
>
> *   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>
> *   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I would like to replace this with something less ugly. Is this possible?

I am running XP and FF 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick googling netted [this](http://tehpost.blogspot.com/2007/02/how-to-change-firefox-error-message.html). Following those instructions should give the result you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's not pretty.  There is a [mozilla forum thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=492177) that explains 2 ways to do it.